# What is a good Rails 3 gem for parsing RSS feeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rss, feed

I stumbled upon [Feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra) but it seems that isn't a Rails gem, but rather just a Ruby gem.

Does anyone know of any good ones for Rails 3 that are still being supported?

Thanks.

Comment: You can still use Feedzirra and wrap it in a model.

Comment: @PedroNascimento Anything more native?

Comment: Ruby gems are native in Ruby. :P Feedzirra provides ways of using it in an AR model.

Comment: Hehehehe....I meant, native to Rails & bundler, etc.

Comment: Did you ever write a wrapper-gem, or make a pull to feedzirra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are any gems for feed parsing that are specific to Rails... I'd suggest just checking out [Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/feed_parsing) to see what's common and available.

And if you end up choosing Feedzirra, here's a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/168-feed-parsing) for it. A little old, but it can still be used in Rails 3.

Answer (score 2):

I'm facing a similar question right now. I'm going with this gem: https://github.com/cardmagic/simple-rss

Comment: Can you please explain, why did you choose that over others?

Comment: It did what I needed, and it is a currently-maintained project. I think I was trying out several RSS parsers at once, and this one was the easiest to use, so after some time I stopped my trials of other gems and used this one.

Answer (score 0):

We created a [Rails Engine](http://blog.superfeedr.com/consuming-rss-feeds-rails/) to consume RSS feed thru Superfeedr. It lets you subscribe, unsubscribe, retrieve past content from feeds and handles notifications of new content on your behalf.

You can get [this gem from there](https://rubygems.org/gems/superfeedr_engine).